# Guest user on Ubuntu 20.04 will not launch Firefox

Tags: firefox, guest-session

I have installed a basic ubuntu 22.04.  Whenever, i launch a Guest session, a new user with a random suffix is created.  When the session is launched, Firerfox silently fails to start on the GUI.  When using the CLI, we get the following error.

```
guest-r1tgtt@myhost:~$ firefox
cannot create user data directory: /tmp/guest-r1tgtt/snap/firefox/2605: Permission denied
guest-r1tgtt@myhost:~$
```

When looking for the mentionned directory, i appears that the directory `/tmp/guest-r1tgtt/snap/firefox` is readable and writable.  The mentioned directory does exists.  The profilactic deletion of the directory does not solve the problem.

On the Internet, peoples want us to reinstall an other version of Firefox, but I would rather use the distribution package, instead of some third-party software.

How to make the guest user to be able to run Firefox as expected?  Where can this bug be signaled?

Comment: It is an apparmor issue (.bug) with snap.  "but I would rather use the distribution package, instead of some third-party software." That is NOT what they mean: you are probably using the snap version and they are stating to use the "apt" version. Still the official Ubuntu version.

Comment: Here's the upstream bug. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1757195